# How to enlarge latex fragments in org mode at the same time as the buffer text?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I'm using `org-mode` in emacs, but I think the question is also relevant for `auctex` users.

In `org-mode` you can show latex fragments, as the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html) demonstrates.

But: these fragments (mostly math formulae) seem to have *constant* size.  When I type `C-x C-+` or `C-x C--` *only* the buffer text size changes.  How can I change the fragments size from the buffer?

(I know I can make the fragments larger or smaller with `org-format-latex-options`, but this is permanent. I want to change the size of the fragments (the png files) like the text.)

Answer (score 5):

Updated answer: (thanks for the feedback)

```
(defun update-org-latex-fragments ()
  (org-latex-preview '(64))
  (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale text-scale-mode-amount)
  (org-latex-preview '(16)))
(add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'update-org-latex-fragments)
```

Old answer:

Here is a start: hook into `text-scale-mode-hook` and update `org-format-latex-options` accordingly.

```
(defun update-org-latex-fragments ()
  (org-toggle-latex-fragment '(16))
  (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale text-scale-mode-amount)
  (org-toggle-latex-fragment '(16)))
(add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'update-org-latex-fragments)
```

A scaling factor might be needed before `text-scale-mode-amount` though...

Comment: No `org-toggle-latex-fragment` function in latest org-mode.

Comment: @user3173715 Your latest is not my latest then...

Comment: you are using development org-mode?

Comment: @user3173715 Use `org-preview-latex-fragment` (obsolete since Aug 2014)

Comment: `org-toggle-latex-fragment` is obsolete since `org 9.3`. Use `org-latex-preview` instead. Moreover, at least at my side, the first `org-toggle-latex-fragment` should take `'(64)` instead. `'(64)` clear images in the buffer, and `'(16)` display them (cf. the doc).

Comment: Works, but if I have a custom font size in my init file, for example in my case `(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Inconsolata-28") (tool-bar-lines . 0) (menu-bar-lines . 0)))` it is to small in each scale (but the difference decreases if you scale up).  Do you have an idea of how to adapt it to a custom default font size?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer from thisirs, I am using the following with success.  The scale factor in this example is 2.3:

```
(defun update-org-latex-fragment-scale ()
  (let ((text-scale-factor (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount)))
    (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale (* 2.3 text-scale-factor)))
)
(add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'update-org-latex-fragment-scale)
```

Note that I have removed the code that toggles the preview, since I prefer to do that manually, and it can take a while if there are many fragments to preview.  This code only adjusts the scale of previewed fragments, so that the next time they are displayed using `C-c C-x C-l`, they will have an appropriate size that matches the text.

Comment: Is hardcoding the factor necessary?

Comment: @T.Verron the scale factor is something that affects how large or small the previewed fragment is with respect to the text size.  The ratio between those two probably depends on the font you're using, and possibly the dpi of your screen.  It may be possible to automate the computation of a scale-factor, but I prefer to just fiddle with it until it looks to my liking.  Note that the "hard-coded scale factor" is not the same as the text-scale-factor, which does automatically change as you zoom your text.

Comment: Oh, ok, indeed I thought that it would be the zoom factor. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

A different, modern solution is to preview latex fragments in Org mode using [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) instead of [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). The package [math-preview](https://gitlab.com/matsievskiysv/math-preview) implements this and with it the font size in the previews is adapted to the font size of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

That is already built-in if you use [`texfrag-mode`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) in Orgmode instead of the built-in LaTeX fragment support of Orgmode.

Just regenerate the LaTeX fragments with <kbd>C-c C-p C-d</kbd> after changing the size with <kbd>C-x C-+ C-+ ...</kbd>. The size of the LaTeX fragments will fit the size of the surrounding text.

Normal text size:

[image: Normal text size]

After pressing <kbd>C-x C-+ C-+ C-x</kbd> and <kbd>C-c C-p C-d</kbd>:

[image]

Sidenote: With the last version of texfrag you can also activate `texfrag-show-last-mode`. With that minor mode activated Texfrag shows the last rendered LaTeX-fragment as handle if you edit the formula:

[image: texfrag-show-last-mode]

Answer (score 0):

Code in other answers is helpful, but it re-renders latex preview on every change of text scale, even if not asked to do so, and even when `C-x C-+` is pressed multiple times in a row, which is slow.

I'd rather do re-render manually. And I'd like `org-format-latex-options` to be left unmodified.

```
(setq my-org-latex-preview-scale 1.0)   ; depends on the font used in emacs or just on user preference
(defun org-latex-preview-advice (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((old-val (copy-tree org-format-latex-options)))     ; plist-put is maybe-destructive, weird. So, we have to restore old value ourselves
    (setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options
                                              :scale
                                              (* my-org-latex-preview-scale (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount))))
    (apply orig-func args)
    (setq org-format-latex-options old-val)))
(advice-add 'org-latex-preview :around #'org-latex-preview-advice)
```