# Org-Mode Latex Preview screen-dependent size

Tags: org-mode, latex

When using the inline latex preview in org-mode, I have discovered that it seems the size of the preview images is dependent on the display size.

While at work, I have my laptop connected to a dock, with an external display. I have then configured the preview with the `:scale` property in my `init.el` file. The scale is set to 1.2.

As I got home, I continued work on my laptop, and when I wrote a new expression in latex and toggled the preview of the expression, the size was significantly larger (see image).

[image: Size different]

Is there a simple way I can fix this and get the size to be equivalent (relative to my text) on all screens?

Comment: Instead of setting the scale to a number (1.2), you can set it to a function (i.e., `preview-scale-from-face`). That should cause the preview to be scaled to match `preview-reference-face`, and you can customize that face to set it to a relative size. I can't test that at the moment, but it sounds like it should be a portable solution.

Comment: @Tyler: I hope you can test that and make it an answer. I'll certainly upvote it!

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Probably related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58591/5422

Answer (score 0):

Solutions in [How to enlarge latex fragments in org mode at the same time as the buffer text?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3387) can help improve this, but I came up with the following (very hacky) solution:

```
(plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale (if (> (display-pixel-width) 3000) 0.8 1.5))
```

I'm not sure if this is robust to things like plugging in new monitors after emacs has started (I don't believe this will work). In that case you should also include some advice around `org-latex-preview`, something like `(advice-add 'org-latex-preview :around #'my-scaling-function-here)`.